# Eclipse C/C++ Console behaving strangely

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, configuration

I intended to use Eclipse with MinGW. But after all the setup done, I got this strange error. Well its not an error actually. I think its a bug. After writing the program and building it, when I

run it, the console remains irresponsive. It works but like this-----

Suppose I am running this code --

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    c = a+b;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

After running the program, the console appears like this--
[image]

When I run this program first, and it appears to be that the `printf()` statements are executing after all the `scanf()` statements are done. Now this problem quickly resolves if one just adds an `fflush(stdout)` after every `printf()`. But there should be some solutions in the terms of configuration and setup, adding an `fflush(stdout)` doesn't look very comfortable to me, imagine it in a menu driven program with 10 or more options. So is there anything else I can do about this?

I have already tried this.

> "
>   `Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings ->` Select the .exe and click `edit ->` go to option `Environment` and select `new` and give `Name = PATH` and `Value = C:\MinGW\bin` "

But sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stdout stream is buffered, so it will display what is in the buffer only after it reaches a newline.

Either use `\n` with each `printf` statement,

or take help of `fflush`,

or try using `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`. `setbuf` will disable buffuring,

or `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);` will also work but you need to call it before any operation on `stdout`,

or use `stderr` for print rather than `stdout` .

Comment: As you can see, I have used "\n" with every printf statement. setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ) is working fine. Can you please explain why this is happening? It doesn't happen when I use MinGW with command line, or using any other IDE like code::blocks or VC++.

Comment: @allocated Terminal is line buffered that is why you are not getting any issue with that and no i can't see that you have used `\n` with line ` printf("%d", c);`

Comment: Oops! I missed that one. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure Eclipse to debug using an external native DOS console, that will solve all your problems.
The procedure is described in details [here](http://nicolas.riousset.com/eclipse-how-to-debug-a-c-console-application-using-a-native-dos-console-instead-of-the-ide-integrated-one/), but in brief :

1. Create your Hello World C++ command line project, from the Eclipse menu File > New > C++ Project
2. In your project folder, create a ".gdbinit" text file. It will contain your gdb debugger configuration
3. Edit ".gdbinit", and add the following line (without quotes) : "set new-console on"
4. In Eclipse, go to menu Run > "Debug Configurations", and select your application name in the left pane
5. In the "debugger" tab, ensure the "GDB command file" now points to your « .gdbinit » file. Else, input the path to your ".gdbinit" configuration file
6. Click « Apply » and « Debug ». You’re done ! A native DOS command line should be launched.